# hex to bytes in chunks

Tags: c#, hex, bytebuffer

I'm using the following code to convert a hex string written in a txt file to a 
byte file. The problem is that it doesn't handles large txt files and I get the
"out of memory exception". I know that it should be done in "chunks" but I just can't
get it right.

Please help! The code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        string tempFileName = (Server.MapPath("~\\Tempfolder\\" + FileUpload2.FileName));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {

            string s = (sr.ReadToEnd());
            if (s.Length % 2 == 1) { lblispis.Text = "String must have an even length"; }
            else
            {
               string hexString = s;
                File.WriteAllBytes(tempFileName + ".bin", StringToByteArray(hexString));
                lblispis.Text = "Done.";
            }
        }
    }                            
 }
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the `ReadToEnd` call with `ReadLine` and wrap it in a loop, if the file format allows that.

If that's not the case, there's always the option to read an even number of characters (`Read(char[], int, int)`) until you hit the end of the file. Of course that way you detect an uneven number of characters very late after having done quite some work already.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Wormbo's answer, note that a hex string only contains twice as much characters as the byte array. In .NET, object size limit is 2GB (2GB is actually the process size limit on a 32-bit machine), but you can easily have problems allocating even ~800MB contiguous blocks due to heap fragmentation.

In other words, you will want to write directly to disk, immediately after converting it:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(hex))
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(bin, FileMode.Create)))
{
     string line;
     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
         writer.Write(StringToByteArray(line));
}
```

**[Edit]**

I've fixed it, parentheses had to be added around the assignment (check the `while` statement above).

Note that this is only a shorthand for something like:

```
     string line = reader.ReadLine();
     while (line != null) 
     {
          writer.Write(...);
          line = reader.ReadLine();
     }
```

Comment: while (line = reader.ReadLine() != null)
"cannot implicitly convert type string to bool"

Comment: if I do this:  string line = reader.ReadLine();                   
                    while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
                   {
                       writer.Write(StringToByteArray(line));
                   }                                                 I get empty file.

Comment: @Ladislav: sorry, I wrote it without checking. It's basically two operations in a single line: 1) read a line into the `line` variable, and 2) check if `line` is null. But the latter operation has precedence, so the compiler tries to assign a bool to the `line` variable. I'll edit.